# Expanding the overlay to fit the browser window

Tags: html, css, popup, overlay

I am developing a html page for a friend using the following template. I want the overlay window to overlap and cover the entire window.
It is like this on the first picture, And I want to appear that black overlay like on the second picture.

https://img.bi/#/6oqwatq!ETDme8r5qEhXIsUMlkpB0xCzdMUY0Ew2TvAekFsD

This is the html code for the page.

```js
$(window).load(function() { 
        $('.page_spinner').fadeOut();
        $('body').css({overflow:'auto', 'min-height':'800px'})
    })
```

```css
.glob {
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     position:absolute;
     overflow:hidden
    }
    
    body {
     font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
     color:#000;
     background:url(../images/bgPart.png);
     line-height:20px;
     min-width:980px;
     min-height:100%;
     position:absolute;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     overflow:hidden
    }
    
    .ic {
     border:0;
     float:right;
     background:#fff;
     color:red;
     width:50%;
     line-height:10px;
     font-size:10px;
     margin:-220% 0 0;
     overflow:hidden;
     padding:0
    }
    
    /* Global Structure ========================================================= */
    .main {
     margin:0 auto;
     width:940px;
     z-index:2;
     height:100%
    }
    
    .page_spinner {
     position:fixed;
     background:url(../images/loader.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat #fbf9f3;
     z-index:99;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     top:0;
     left:0
    }
    
    #glob {
     position:relative;
     overflow:hidden;
     z-index:1
    }
    
    #content {
     position:relative;
     height:540px;
     z-index:1;
     width:720px;
     float:left;
     display:inline-block;
     overflow:hidden
    }
    
    #content > ul {
     width:100%;
     height:540px;
     z-index:1;
     position:relative
    }
    
    #content > ul > li {
     width:100%;
     display:block;
     position:absolute;
     overflow:hidden
    }
    
    .box {
     height:480px;
     width:660px;
     background:url(../images/extra1.png);
     margin:30px;
     position:relative
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="glob">
    <div class="page_spinner"></div>
    <div class="main">
    <div class="center"><!--header -->
    <div class="headerHolder">
    <header>
    <div class="logoHolder">
    <h1><a href="#!/pageGallery" id="logo">oratorio</a></h1>
    </div>
    </header>
    <div class="followHolder"><span>Call Us: +1 (800) 12 34 567</span>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/followIcon1.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/followIcon2.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img alt="" src="images/followIcon3.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--header end-->
    <div class="menuHolder">
    <nav class="menu">
    <ul id="menu">
    <li class="with_ul"><a href="#!/pageAbout"><span class="overPlane"></span><span class="mText">about</span></a>
    <ul class="submenu_1">
    <li><a href="#!/pageMore">Welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/pageMore">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/pageMore">History</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#!/pageServices"><span class="overPlane"></span><span class="mText">services</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/pageGallery"><span class="overPlane"></span><span class="mText">gallery</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/pagePrivacy"><span class="overPlane"></span><span class="mText">privacy</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/pageContact"><span class="overPlane"></span><span class="mText">contacts</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
    <!--content -->
    <article id="content">
    <div class="ic">More Website Templates @ TemplateMonster.com. May 07, 2012!</div>
    <div class="iconHolder">
    <div id="img_slider">
    <ul>
    <li>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon1.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon2.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon3.jpg"></a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon4.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon5.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon6.jpg"></a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon7.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon8.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon9.jpg"></a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon1.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon2.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon3.jpg"></a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon4.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon5.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon6.jpg"></a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon7.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon8.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon9.jpg"></a></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon4.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon6.jpg"></a></div>
    <div class="picHold"><a class="pic" href="images/image-blank.png" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomSp"></span><img alt="" src="images/galleryIcon5.jpg"></a></div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="next"><img alt="" src="images/gallNext1.png"></a> <a href="#" id="prev"><img alt="" src="images/gallPrev1.png"></a></div>
    <ul>
    <li id="pageAbout">
    <div class="box">
    <div class="closePlane"><a class="closeButton" href="#!/pageGallery"><img alt="" src="images/closeIcon.png"></a></div>
    <div class="containerContent">
    <h2>Welcome to Our Studio!</h2>
    <div class="col1 padBot1">
    <figure class="_fig1"><img alt="" src="images/page1pic1.png"></figure>
    <div class="col2">
    <p>Cream is one of <a class="_link1" href="http://blog.templatemonster.com/category/free-website-templates/">free website templates</a> created by TemplateMonster.com team. This website template is optimized for 1280X1024 screen resolution. It is also XHTML &amp; CSS valid. The PSD source files of this <a class="_link1" href="http://blog.templatemonster.com/2012/05/07/free-full-javascript-animated-template-web-design-studio/">Cream Template</a> are available for free for the registered members of TemplateMonster.com. Feel free to get them!</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col1 padBot2">
    <div class="col3 bord1 magRight1">
    <ul class="_list1">
    <li><a href="#">At vero eos et accusam justo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Stet clitasd gubergren nosea takimata</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Duo dolores et sed diam rebum</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col3">
    <ul class="_list1">
    <li><a href="#">Ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sadipscing elitr clitasdd diam nonumy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">At vero eos et accusam et justo</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <a class="moreButton" href="#!/pageMore">Read More</a></div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li id="pageServices">
    <div class="box">
    <div class="closePlane"><a class="closeButton" href="#!/pageGallery"><img alt="" src="images/closeIcon.png"></a></div>
    <div class="containerContent">
    <h2>What We Can Do</h2>
    <div class="col1 padBot3">
    <div class="col4 magRight2">
    <h3><a class="_link3" href="#">Website Designing</a></h3>
    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hen drerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col4">
    <h3><a class="_link3" href="#">Reputation Management</a></h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col1">
    <div class="col4 magRight2">
    <h3><a class="_link3" href="#">Flash Development</a></h3>
    <p>Paesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy euismod tincidunt ut laoreet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col4">
    <h3><a class="_link3" href="#">3D Modeling and Animation</a></h3>
    <p>Dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li id="pageGallery"></li>
    <li id="pagePrivacy">
    <div class="box">
    <div class="closePlane"><a class="closeButton" href="#!/pageGallery"><img alt="" src="images/closeIcon.png"></a></div>
    <div class="containerContent">
    <h2>Privacy Policy</h2>
    <div class="col1">
    <div class="Btns1"><a class="upBtn" href="#"></a> <a class="downBtn" href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="scroll1">
    <p class="padBot4">Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
    <p class="padBot4">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit.</p>
    <p>Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li id="pageContact">
    <div class="box">
    <div class="closePlane"><a class="closeButton" href="#!/pageGallery"><img alt="" src="images/closeIcon.png"></a></div>
    <div class="containerContent">
    <div class="col5 magRight3">
    <h2>feedback</h2>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <form action="#" id="ContactForm" name="ContactForm">
    <div class="success">Contact form submitted!&nbsp;We will be in touch soon.</div>
    <fieldset class="left">
    <div class="block"><label class="name padRight3"><span class="title1">Name:</span> <span class="bg"><input class="input" type="text" value=""></span> <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span></label> <label class="email"><span class="title1">Email:</span> <span class="bg"><input class="input" type="email" value=""></span> <span class="error">*This is not a valid email address.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span></label> <label class="name padRight3"><span class="title1">Phone:</span> <span class="bg"><input class="input" type="tel" value=""></span> <span class="error">*This is not a valid number.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span></label></div>
    <div class="block"><label class="message"><span class="title1">Message:</span> <span class="bg">
    <textarea cols="2" rows="1">
    </textarea></span> <span class="error">*The message is too short.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span></label></div>
    <div class="formButtons">
    <div class="formBtn"><a class="moreButton" data-type="submit" href="#">Send</a></div>
    <div class="formBtn"><a class="moreButton" data-type="reset" href="#">Clear</a></div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col5">
    <h2>Contacts</h2>
    <div class="padBot5">
    <figure class="google_map"></figure>
    </div>
    <div class="col5">
    <p><span>8901 Marmora Road,<br>
    Glasgow, D04 89GR.</span><br>
    <span class="space1">Telephone:</span>+1 800 603 6035<br>
    <span>E-mail:&nbsp;<a class="_link1" href="mailto:">mail@demolink.org</a></span></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li id="pageMore">
    <div class="box">
    <div class="closePlane"><a class="closeButton" href="#!/pageGallery"><img alt="" src="images/closeIcon.png"></a></div>
    <div class="containerContent">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <div class="col1">
    <div class="Btns2"><a class="upBtn" href="#"></a> <a class="downBtn" href="#"></a></div>
    <div class="scroll2">
    <p class="padBot4">Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
    <p class="padBot4">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit.</p>
    <p>Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </article>
    <!--content end-->
    <!--footer -->
    <footer><!-- {%FOOTER_LINK} -->
    <div class="mainFooter">
    <div class="privHold">
    <pre class="textPrivacy">
    &copy; 2012 Cream<br><span class="color4">Website Template</span> by <a class="_link2" href="http://www.templatemonster.com/" rel="nofollow">TemplateMonster.com</a> | <a class="_link2" href="http://www.html5xcss3.com/" rel="nofollow">Html5xcss3.com</a>
    </pre></div>
    </div>
    </footer>
    <!--footer end--></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I tried changing the values of box in css but it is not helping. Please guide me in the right direction. Thanks...

Comment: what class refers to the overlay, because it is not clear from the code you posted..

Comment: http://1drv.ms/1BDI3bs code for the javascript

Comment: The box class refers to the overlay. I am editing the code now you will be able to find it better.

Comment: a live link, or a jsfiddle would go a long way

Comment: I am new to jsfiddle but I have temporarily uploaded in a live url www.mgpmhome.org

Comment: ok kudos! so you want the black overaly to be 100% height and width of the entire window? and should it cover(be on top of) everything on the page?

Comment: Please reduce your markup to a minimal example. Presently, it's full of "irrelevant" code.

Comment: Just a heads up to everyone working on this. The template is http://templates.websitetemplatesonline.com/Free-Cream-Studio-Theme/index.html#!/pageGallery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need some changes/new rules to your CSS

```
#content {
    /*This makes the content section (which includes the overlay) 
      to appear over everything - so that menu/logos etc do not show 
      over the overlay*/
    z-index: 100; 
}
.box {
    /*this removes the current way the overlay appears*/
    background: none; 
}

/*
Following rule creates the overlay you want.
This will not slide though, it will appear in place
*/
.box:before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    background: url("../images/extra1.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this looks fine, Can I make the content inside the new box class to fit the full overlay?

Comment: you could apply the `.box:before` properties to the `.box` (*and remove the `.box:before` rule*).

Comment: When I use the box:before properties in .box, the contents are overlapping when the transition happens while navigating through the pages. But it's not happening if bot .box and .box:before are used.

Answer (score 0):

In css use opacity and background-size

Comment: Hey, thanks but if I increase the background size it got wrapped up on the right and bottom. Check the screenshot. https://img.bi/#/IACsKS1!MGStqtJ5T3mVRvc80SUb9c7iwoV0c5d3NuXPqAT3